# Count unique values after grouping data and save unique values in a new column in python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count

Im trying to group data and count unique values of each group and then save the unique values in a new column.
Ive tried using the code below to solve the issue but my new column keeps coming up with NaN and no counts. All the responses I've seen on stack overflow have some variation of this from like 4 years ago not sure if the syntax has changed?

```
df['counts'] = df.groupby(["A","B"])["C"].transform('nunique')
```

the code below gives me the exact thing I'm looking for but I can't call on the column with the unique values because the column has no name. Looking down the line I'm expecting to rank the highest unique values for each group.

```
df.groupby(["A","B"])["C"].nunique()
```

Expecting new column to have count values in them with column name "counts"

Comment: Nothing has changed. Can you give a code example that generates a count column of `NaN` instead of the values? As for your second code example, the values are in the `.index`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the first method that you shared and it worked for me. My code:

```
import pandas as pd
#creating a random dataframe
dctf =  {"A":["First","First","First","First","First","First","Second","Second","Second","Second","Second","Third","Third","Third","Third","Third"],
      "B":["one","two","one","two","one","two","one","two","three","one","two","three","three","one","two","three"],
      "C":["Apple","Orange","Leaf","foo","Leaf","Apple","foo","Leaf","Apple","Apple","Orange","Orange","Orange","foo","foo","Leaf"]
      }
df = pd.DataFrame(dctf)

#answer
df['counts']=df.groupby(["A","B"])["C"].transform('nunique')
```

This returns the following output for me:

```
    A       B     C     counts
0   First   one   Apple  2
1   First   two   Orange 3
2   First   one   Leaf   2
3   First   two   foo    3
4   First   one   Leaf   2
5   First   two   Apple  3
6   Second  one   foo    2
7   Second  two   Leaf   2
8   Second  three Apple  1
9   Second  one   Apple  2
10  Second  two   Orange 2
11  Third   three Orange 2
12  Third   three Orange 2
13  Third   one   foo    1
14  Third   two   foo    1
15  Third   three Leaf   2
```

You should share the sample of your dataset and code where you are getting the NaN values, as well as a sample of desired result if this does not help.

Comment: what if I wanted only the top values of the count to appear such as: First two 3, Second one 2, Third three 2

Comment: You can again groupby on the result of answer like: df.groupby(['A']).max() Which will give the top value of counts. If you want to see all top values for column A you can do the same groupby operation with two columns df.groupby(['A','B']).max().